# Zero divisor ax=b Proof reasoning check?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have to prove that if $(R,+,\cdot )$ is a ring and $a \in R$ is a zero divisor, then for all $b\in R$, the equation $ax=b$ has either no solution or many solutions. I've been going at it for a couple of hours, but I get nowhere.

To my reasoning, if $a$ is a zero divisor then $a \neq 0$, so that leaves $b$ being either $0$ or not $0$, if $b \neq 0$ then $ax=b$ can have many solutions depending on what value is $b$, but if $b=0$ then since $a$ is a zero divisor then at least there exists a value that $ay=0$, so let it be the case that $x=y$ and there we have at least one solution.$$$$ What am I doing wrong? or what concept am I not understanding? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to start with the fact that there is a nonzero $y$ such that $ay=0$. If there is an $x$ such that $ax=b$, now find another one.  This is similar to finding such things in basic linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ka=0$.

Then $ax=b $ means $kax=kb $ so $0=kb $.

Well, if that isn't true there can't be any solutions.  If however it does happen to be the case that $kb=0$,  well there still might not be any solution.

But if there is *one* solution so that $ax=b $ then for any integer $m $, $a (x+m*k)=ax+m*ak=ax=b $.  So there are many.

Comment: But if $kb=0$ that would imply that $b=0$ right? and if that's the case the solution for $x$ would be $0$?? being that $k$ and $a$ are non zero

Comment: Oh, got it, many thanks! :D

Comment: I'd would mean b is also a zero divisor.  And a divisor that shares a quotient with a.  Although I might have pulled a fast one on you with equating divisors with right divisors.